# "Shout to" somebody near to you

Tags: prepositions

> If you speak very loudly to someone who is near to you, for example
> because you are angry with them, you **shout at/✳to** them.
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/EnglishUsage/shout

Can't you **shout to** somebody who is *near to* you?

Secondly, if you are angry at somebody that's not near to you, do you **shout at** or **to** them?

Comment: To "shout to" someone means to shout because the environment requires it to communicate. It could be the distance, or a loud environment, or the other person is wearing hearing protection. So yes, if it's very noisy where you are, you could *shout to* someone who's right beside you. "Shout to" does not mean angry shouting.

Comment: You can, but that's not the usual usage. Don't use it unless you have complicating circumstances.

Comment: The meaning difference between "shout to" and "shout at" may not be absolute, but *typically* if you want to give a connotation of shouting out of frustration or anger with somebody, "shout at" is better; and if you want to give a connotation of shouting because someone may have difficulty hearing you, "shout to" is better.

Answer (score 1):

I'd shout at someone nearby, not shout to.
If I'm angry, I shout at someone far away, not shout to. If I shout to someone far away, it's not obvious or necessary that I'm angry.